# ligbdx touch listener on wrong screen

Tags: android, libgdx

Recently started to write a MenuScreen using libgdx with Tables/Stage/Buttons etc However I've realised that even after going to the next Screen, the original MenuScreen's buttons are still clickable :(

This is roughly what happens:

1. App starts, see `MainMenu` screen
2. Click on a button (eg: "Options"), see Options screen
3. Click somewhere in Options screen where a button from MainMenu used to be (eg. About)
4. Taken to the About screen

When you see the Options screen, if you **don't** click on somewhere where the the MainMenu has a button, then the Options screen works as normal/expected.

So from this behaviour, it seems like the MainMenu screen is still present (just hidden) and all the button listeners are still active.

What is the proper way of cleaning up the MainMenu screen? (and I suppose cleaning up libgdx screens in general)

The important bits of code:

```
public class MainMenu implements Screen {

    public MainMenu() {
        // ..setting up font, camera etc

        stage = new Stage();
        stage.setCamera(camera);
        Table table = new Table();
        table.setWidth(300);
        table.setHeight(480);
        stage.addActor(table);

        TextButton options = new TextButton("Options", buttonStyle);
        options.addListener(new ButtonClickListener(app.options));
        table.add(options).pad(20);
        table.row();        

        // ... more buttons, eg About...

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }


    private class ButtonClickListener extends ClickListener {
        private final Screen screen;

        private ButtonClickListener(Screen screen) {
            this.screen = screen;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            app.setScreen(this.screen);
        }
    }

    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();

        spriteBatch.begin();
        stage.draw();
        spriteBatch.end();
    }

    // ... show(), resize(), hide(), pause(), resume() are all no-ops

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        spriteBatch.dispose();
        font.dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your stage is still processing the input. It doesnt matter whether it's visible or not. Unless the new screen sets a new processor you should remove it manually. You should also call dispose manually because it's never called automatically (libgdx only calls hide()).

So, you can dispose and remove the processor inside hide();

```
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null);
this.dispose()
```

Comment: Interesting, I 'fixed' the issue i had by clearing the stage - though resetting the Gdx.input also seems to make sense. Will also look into manually calling dispose() (do it in some places already)

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar issue but fortunately I came across one solution, even Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(null); did not help.

Solution: Please add **stage.clear();** in the hide(){} method, This significantly solved the same issue.